# Sorting an array [QuickSort] still slower than native Range.Sort

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I'm recently developing a rather large project and one of the pieces is efficient sorting. As I never had to sort anything of this magnitude with VBA I did not know it would be so challenging.

I created a sample by creating a series of numbers from 1 to 500. Then I modified them with 'custom format' to look like "000000" meaning 1 is 000001, 15 is 000015, 1537 is 001537 etc. then I added two letters in front of all of those, say XY.

My sample looks like:

```
XY000001
XY000002
.
.
XY000500
```

Finally I filled this sample down from row 1 to row 100,000 to have (100,000 / 500) 200 of such samples **note the sample goes from 1 to 500 and then repeats again from 1 to 500**. (This resembles the kind of data I would want to work with, however in my sample I can have any number from XY000001 up to XY999999).

**Now what I want to do is sort the sample as quickly as possible.**

I went through lots of different trials, one of them was using the `QuickSort` code I found somewhere online.

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuickSort(a As Variant, aLB As Long, aUB As Long)

Dim vPivot  As Variant
Dim vSwap   As Variant
Dim LO  As Long
Dim HI   As Long


    LO = aLB
    HI = aUB
    vPivot = a((aLB + aUB) / 2, 1)

    While (LO <= HI) 'divide

        While (a(LO, 1) < vPivot And LO < aUB)
            LO = LO + 1
        Wend

        While (vPivot < a(HI, 1) And HI > aLB)
            HI = HI - 1
        Wend

        If (LO <= HI) Then

            vSwap = a(LO, 1)
            a(LO, 1) = a(HI, 1)
            a(HI, 1) = vSwap
            LO = LO + 1
            HI = HI - 1

        End If

    Wend

    If (aLB < HI) Then QuickSort a, aLB, HI

    If (LO < aUB) Then QuickSort a, LO, aUB

End Sub
```

Now comes the *funny* part - the above code is supposed to be really fast.

Guess what, **it takes the `QuickSort` code around 450-600ms** on my computer to sort the sample data I described above, **while a simple `Range.Sort` needs only about 60-70ms** (keep in mind that Range.Sort also 'happens' directly on the Worksheet while the `QuickSort` is performing operations in memory on the array, so `QuickSort` in theory should be much faster).

I generally tend do do everything on arrays in VBA as I know how much performance the code gains, however in this instance I am puzzled.

I can't fathom how the native `Range.Sort` can be so blazing fast. The same goes for simply clicking on the native 'Sort A-Z' button in Excel - seems ultra quick.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something or do people actually NOT sort in arrays?

**PS: If more data is needed please ask for it in the comments.**

Comment: "Range.Sort also 'happens' directly on the Worksheet" - really more accurate to say that the *results* of the sort show up on the worksheet: the actual sorting probably happens in highly-optimized code within the Excel application object.

Comment: I have no doubt that the Excel code for sorting is optimized, HOWEVER what I meant was that most of the native excel functions are much slower than operating on arrays, and especially when you don't disable events like `ScreenUpdating` or do not turn `AutomaticCalculation` off. In my example I did neither and still the native Excel code was ~10x faster than `QuickSort` which is a bit strange to me.

Comment: "most of the native excel functions are much slower than operating on arrays" - this is not really always true when performing real like-for-like comparisons.  What is true for sure is that performing cell-by-cell operations is relatively slow, and reading the data into an array and iterating over the array typically is much faster.   However things like Match() for example are much faster when the data is on a worksheet than when run against an array.

Comment: Fair point again Tim. As far as I'm concerned functions like `Match()` or `Index()` are great - you can for example get all the predefined rows from an array in *one sweep*, however most of those fail when the number of items (rows) is larger than 60k or 100k. My data set is much bigger than that. I chose 100,000 rows as a benchmark, but the files I'm operating on reach nearly the end of the sheet at times.
Certainly if I don't find anything faster I will copy array to a temporary worksheet, sort in place and copy back to the array, however I'm silently hoping there are faster methods!

Comment: I guess when you're close to 1M records then you're not going to get blazing fast VBA, but then again just opening the files is pretty slow too, so your overall time spent in VBA might be less significant....